# Regular expression problem(s) in Bash: [^negate] doesn't seem to work

Tags: linux, bash, grep, regular-expression, crunchbang

When I execute `ls /directory | grep '[^term]'` in Bash I get a regular listing, as if the `grep` command is ignored somehow. I tried the same thing with `egrep`, I tried to use it with double and single quotes, but to no better results. When I try `ls /directory | grep '^[term]` I get all entries beginning with term - as expected.

I have tried out this command in an online editor, where I can [test my regex](http://www.regexe.de/) and it worked as it should. But not in Bash. So it works in a simulation, but not in real life.

I work on Crunchbang Linux 10. I hope this is enough information and am looking forward to every hint, because failing to execute on such a basic level and wasting hours of time is really frustrating!

Comment: I am confused because of the negate in the title. Do you want to `grep` lines starting with term. Or do you want to grep for lines not containing term at all?

Comment: @Bernhard: I want a listing without the term in the square brackets. It doesn't have to be 'term' exactly! As far as I understood it, [^abc] means that anything containing a, b or c or any combination of it should not be in the listing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you sure what you want is happening?
When you run `ls /directory | grep '[^term]'` you are essentially grepping for not the letters t e r m. This means if a file has other letters in its name it will still appear in the output of `ls`. Take the following directory for instance:

```
$ ls
alpha  brave  bravo  charlie  delta
```

Now if I run `ls |grep '^[brav]'` I get the following:

```
$ ls |grep '^[brav]'
alpha
brave
bravo
```

As you can see, not only did I get `brave` and `bravo` I also got `alpha` because the character class `[]` will get any letter from that list.

Consequently, if I run `ls |grep '[^brav]'` I will get all the files that do not contain the characters b r a v **anywhere** in the name.

```
$ ls |grep '[^brav]'
alpha
bravo
brave
charlie
delta
```

If you notice it included the entire directory listing because all the files had at least **one** letter that was not included in the character class.

So as Kanvuanza said, to grep for the inverse of "term" as opposed to the characters `t e r m` you should do it using `grep -v`.

For instance:

```
$ ls |grep -v 'brav'
alpha
charlie
delta
```

Also if you don't want the files that have any characters in the class use `grep -v '[term]'`. That will keep any files from showing up that have any of those characters. (Kanvuanza's answer)

For instance:

```
$ ls |grep -v '[brav]'
```

As you can see there were no files listed because all the files in this directory included at least one letter from that class.

**Addendum:**

I wanted to add that using PCRE it is possible to use just regex to filter out using negate expressions. To do this you would use something known as a negative look-ahead regex: `(?!<regex>)`.

So using the example above, you can do something like this to get results you want without using `grep` flags.

```
$ ls | grep -P '^(?!brav)'
alpha
charlie
delta
```

To deconstruct that regex, it first matches on a start of a line `^` and then looks for strings that do not match `brav` to follow afterwards. Only `alpha`, `charlie`, and `delta` match so those are the only ones that are printed.

Comment: _This means if a file has other letters in its name it will still appear in the output of ls._ This answers quite a few questions! :)
So the best way for the moment seems to be the `-v` option. Thanks for your support! This question really ruined my afternoon, where your answer brightens my evening!

Comment: +1 for `negative look-ahead regex`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that `grep -v` flag does what you want. From the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep):

```
-v, --invert-match
    Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
```

You can use `ls /directory | grep -v [term]` to print any non matching lines.

Comment: I am aware of this option, but am I wrong in assuming that [^xyz] is the opposite of [xyz] and should work in any case?
I also want to avoid editing any settings anywhere on such a basic level. Using an inverting option and/or editing settings sure is a nice way around, but as far as I understood it, this should work without, out of the box.

Comment: I guess you're right, that is the common notation for class negation (ie. `[^abc]`. But I'm pretty sure that grep don't support class negations, except a few standard ones (eg. `[[:^digits:]]`). Grep support for negation is horrible!

Comment: _Grep support for negation is horrible!_ And this are the hints that are the real icing on the cake. I have the same issues with egrep and I'm far away from using [at least for me seemingly] more advanced commands at the moment.
Can you suggest a command that provides better results and less headache?

Comment: @cellar.dweller, `grep`'s handling of character classes is just fine. It just means something quite different than what you (mis)understand. `[abc]` means one of `a`, `b`, or `c`; `[^abc]` means anything _but_ the above. It is _one_ character.

Comment: @cellar.dweller: I think your biggest issue is a misunderstanding of regex, specifically character classes within regex.

Comment: @Kanvuanza, the correct syntax is e.g. `[^[:digit:]]`, and my (limited) tests show it works for all the standard classes.

Comment: @vonbrand I just tried `ls /dir | grep '[^[:digit:]]'` and got a regular listing which contains also files with numbers in it. Same goes for egrep.

Comment: @cellar.dweller, you are asking for all files whose names include one non-digit. The only files which won't match are those with names only digits.

Comment: after trying out quite some cominations I finally seem to have understood. Also, where the problem in understanding it was. It is day two for me in learning about Regular Expressions and I am grateful for your patience. Thanks you very much.

Comment: @vonbrand, now I understand it. Thanks you too.