# grep two conditions, one negated, without a pipeline?

Tags: grep

Assume we have the following `test.txt`:

```
# commented line, no match
# commented line, would match /app/
# again commented, would match app
non commented line, matchin /app
non commented line, no match
```

I would like to get all lines that contain the word '`app`', - but **not** those that have a comment, - and I would like the filename to be output.

The trivial `grep -H 'app' test.txt`, obviously, matches everything and does not avoid lines starting with number/hash character `#`:

[image: term1.png]

A pipeline with a second grep with `-v, --invert-match` option generally messes up the colors, and to preserve the `-H` filenames, I would not be able to specify a negated match for `^#` (i.e. a number/hash character at the start of a line) so I'd have to use a beast like `grep -H app test.txt --color=always | grep -v '\[K:.\[m.\[K#'` to preserve colors:

[image: term2.png]

... but only after doing something like `grep -H app test.txt --color=always | hexdump -C` so I can see the right combo of characters, which is, mildly speaking, tedious.

And unfortunately, seemingly one cannot use the `-v` option to specify its own (negated) pattern in a combo with `-e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN` option which can specify multiple search patterns:

```
:tmp$ grep -H -e 'app' -v '^#' test.txt
grep: ^#: No such file or directory
test.txt:# commented line, no match
test.txt:non commented line, no match
test.txt:
```

Here, `grep` interprets `'^#'` to be a filename, not a search pattern - so the `-v` inverts the matching of `app`, and I get the wrong results from the expected one. Otherwise, in this example, the expected output is only one line:

```
test.txt:non commented line, matchin /app
```

... with properly colored filename, and matches.

So, is there a way to achieve this - but without the messy pipeline given above, and simply using `^#` as the pattern to be avoided?

Comment: @Theophrastus that's a good idea I think - except it won't match the pattern `app` if it happens to be at the very start of the line: perhaps match a word boundary *or* any character except # e.g. `grep -HE --color=always '^(\b|[^#]).*app'`?

Comment: Something similar, via https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/ and PCRE negative look-ahead: the following command matches only lines that do not start with any ammount of whitespace followed by `//`, but contain the word `myword`: `grep -rnP '^(?![[:space:]]*//).*myword' --include='*.cxx'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grep -E '^([^#].*)?app' ./infiles* /dev/null
```

I guess the comments already nearly had it anyway, but if you make the head of line `[^#]` not-comment match `?`optional, then you either get lines that begin with the match *app* or you get lines which begin with something else and then eventually match *app* - but either way, you don't get lines that begin with `#`.

Regarding the colors - well... that depends on the `grep` and the regexp, but a standard GNU grep should highlight the whole match up to the last *app* match. If you would like it more specific you can do `info grep` to have a look at what environment vars a GNU `grep` will consider when highlighting and configure them appropriately , or, failing a satisfactory result in that vein, highlight it yourself.

Comment: Many thanks @mikeserv and the comments - this works, just note that in my example, the entire line is highlighted, as this answer also warns about. Cheers!